# Populate a list with wsdl data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, soap, wsdl

I need to achieve this:

1. a SharePoint page (form) with 2 fields, firstname and lastname
2. connect to a wsdl and get info for parameters firstname and lastname
3. on the same SharePoint page, show the results coming back from the wsdl

I know SharePoint but have no idea how to start on this. Any help is welcome. And it might be done using Designer, or SP OOTB, ...

Comment: What do you need to do is submit the data to a web service ryt?

Comment: Are you using SP2013?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach:

1. Put a Script Editor Webpart to your page, below or above the fields
2. Create a script element and put there a script, that would perform the following:

   - get values of First name and Last name fields
   - perform the web service call
   - display the results

### Get field values

I assume you're using OOTB list form, so in this case field values can be acquired via CSR.

Go to your form page, open developer console (F12->Console tab in IE), and execute the following code:

```
document.querySelector("#onetIDListForm div[webpartid]").id
```

You will see something like this:

[image]

In my case it is "WebPartWPQ2". You need "WPQ2" part of this string. Now you can get the CSR context object for this webpart.

```
var csrContext = window["WPQ2FormCtx"];
```

Having the context, it is very simple to get the field values:

```
var firstName = window["WPQ2FormCtx"].ListData["FirstName"];
var lastName = window["WPQ2FormCtx"].ListData["Title"]; // this is Last name for OOTB Contacts list
```

Note: Please use **internal** names of your fields. E.g. it might be `First_x0020_Name`, because if you create fields manually, spaces are transformed into `_x0020_`. The example above is for the OOTB Contacts list.

[image]

### Web Service Call

Now, you have First name and Last name values. How do you perform soap request and get the results?

I recommend leveraging an opensource library for that purpose. There are plenty of those. For example:

- http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/

Or if you don't want to meddle with libraries, then have a look at this SO answer, that provides example code for accessing SOAP web service from JS.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133/361687

### Displaying results

If you're content with having your data below or above the list form, then you can simply add something like `<div id="mydiv"></div>` into the Script Editor WebPart, and then `$get('mydiv').innerHTML = '... html here, based on received results ...';` will do the trick.

If you need to put the data you receive from the Web Service **inside** the form rather than below or above, you then might want to read the following CodeProject article, explaining in detail how that can be done using CSR (see section "Example: manipulating form layout"):

- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms)